# Find the "top left/top right/bottom left/bottom right" coordinates of a four-cornered polygon from the perspective of a single point/coordinate

Tags: c#, graph

I need to find which of four coordinates is equal to the

1. top left
2. top right
3. bottom left
4. bottom right

*from the perspective* of a single point/coordinate.

The format of my data is: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4], [x1, y1]]`

The polygon that this array of coordinates creates could be located in either of the four quadrants around a central point. I need to find which of the `(x?, y?)` is the respective corner as if I were standing at the central point and looking at the polygon.

Each polygon represents a row in my stadium and I want to plot `n` number of seats along that polygon. I know that my seats are numbered increasing from left-to-right clockwise around the stadium, but I need to know what's the "left" side of the polygon, and what's the "right" side (plus top and bottom).

I could probably figure this out using `if` statements (I'm using C# to plot the seats), but I'm wondering if there is a way to mathematically determine the respective corners from a center point.

Comment: You could use a LINQ expression to dertermine the points, like `var topleft = data.where(d => d.x <= center.x && d.y >= center.y)` and so on.

Comment: The problem is that the polygons could be anywhere *around* the center point, so the "top left" corner could have a d.x greater than, or sometimes less than the center.x. I could find what quadrant the polygon is in to determine what conditions to use I just think it's very iterative and I feel like there should be a better solution.

Comment: Also, that code does not work because it does not truly determine which of the `(xa, ya)` coordinates are truly the top left because your condition could be satisfied by all four points in my coordinate array.

Comment: OK, so to me the "center" was the center of the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I acknowledge I'm providing a partial answer. I'm doing so because the combination of the question `Find the "top left/top right/bottom left/bottom right" coordinates of a four-cornered polygon from the perspective of a single point/coordinate` and the sample dataset with 5 values throws me. Which 4 values in the sample dataset represents the four-cornered polygon and what does the 5th value represent? I think the 5th value represents the `single point/coordinate`, but I'm not sure which of the 5 in the sample is which.

Anyway: Given 4 x,y coordinates, I believe you can determine top left, bottom left, top right, and bottom right by doing a two-level sort on a 4 x 2 list that is loaded with the four x,y coordinates.

Example: Given `List<(int x, int y)> xyList = new List<(int x, int y)>();`, load `xyList` with the four x,y coordinates (order doesn't matter).

```
xyList.Add((13, 404));
xyList.Add((452, 404));
xyList.Add((13, 428));
xyList.Add((452, 428));
```

Then, do a two-level sort on `xyList`:

`var sortedXyList = xyList.OrderBy(list => list.x).ThenBy(list => list.y);`

`sortedXyList` will be:

```
row 0 is top left
row 1 is bottom left
row 2 is top right
row 3 is bottom right
```

Example `sortedXyList`:

```
13  404
13  428
452 404
452 428
```